# About Brightness adjustement

Tags: grub2

On my HP Victus Ryzen laptop with AMD 6500 graphics with Ubuntu 22.04 I can't change screen brightness. When I press the fuctions key a popup appears, but screen brightness is still default. I tried this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

But after that by pressing function keys literally nothing happens, even the popup doesn't show. Please help.